# How to find all numeric columns in data

Tags: r

I'm trying to find all names of columns that only have `numeric` data in them.  For this I'm making use of `is.numeric` and applying it over my data like this:

```
> sapply(ds[vars], is.numeric)
      MinTemp       MaxTemp      Rainfall   Evaporation      Sunshine   WindGustDir WindGustSpeed    WindDir9am    WindDir3pm  WindSpeed9am 
         TRUE          TRUE          TRUE          TRUE          TRUE         FALSE          TRUE         FALSE         FALSE          TRUE 
 WindSpeed3pm   Humidity9am   Humidity3pm   Pressure9am   Pressure3pm      Cloud9am      Cloud3pm       Temp9am       Temp3pm     RainToday 
         TRUE          TRUE          TRUE          TRUE          TRUE          TRUE          TRUE          TRUE          TRUE         FALSE 
 RainTomorrow 
        FALSE
```

The above makes sense according to my data. Column `WindGustDir` and `WindDir9am` for example have values like `NW` so thats why they are `FALSE`.

When I apply this on my data to get names of all columns that are numeric, I DON'T expect to see columns that are non-numeric - for example `WindGustDir` and `WindDir9am`. However, I'm seeing it `WindDir9am` and not `WindGustDir`. **Question** I don't understand why is this the case. How can I fix it so I only get numeric columns?

```
> numerics <- names(ds)[which(sapply(ds[vars], is.numeric))]
> numerics
 [1] "Date"         "Location"     "MinTemp"      "MaxTemp"      "Rainfall"     "Sunshine"     "WindDir9am"   "WindDir3pm"   "WindSpeed9am"
[10] "WindSpeed3pm" "Humidity9am"  "Humidity3pm"  "Pressure9am"  "Pressure3pm"  "Cloud9am"     "Cloud3pm"
```

Here is the link to the data I'm using: http://rattle.togaware.com/weather.csv

**Edit**

```
> vars
 [1] "MinTemp"       "MaxTemp"       "Rainfall"      "Evaporation"   "Sunshine"     
 [6] "WindGustDir"   "WindGustSpeed" "WindDir9am"    "WindDir3pm"    "WindSpeed9am" 
[11] "WindSpeed3pm"  "Humidity9am"   "Humidity3pm"   "Pressure9am"   "Pressure3pm"  
[16] "Cloud9am"      "Cloud3pm"      "Temp9am"       "Temp3pm"       "RainToday"    
[21] "RainTomorrow"
```

Comment: whatever `[vars]` is, remove it and everything should work as expected.

Comment: `which` is actually not necessary

Comment: @flodel >_< that works. I'm very new to R. Can you please explain why this was happening? I've updated to show what `vars` is

Comment: @RichardScriven, but using `which` is marginally faster. There's a question about it somewhere here on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do:

```
which(sapply(ds[vars], is.numeric))
```

you get the indices of the numeric columns of `ds[vars]` (not `ds`). So if you want to get back at names, it is important you apply it to `names(ds[vars])` and not `names(ds)` which has different columns.

```
names(ds[vars])[which(sapply(ds[vars], is.numeric))]
```

You can also just do:

```
vars[which(sapply(ds[vars], is.numeric))]
```

and even use logical indexing like Richard suggested:

```
vars[sapply(ds[vars], is.numeric)]
```

Last, I would consider whether `var` is useful at all, see if doing the work directly on `df`:

```
names(df)[sapply(ds, is.numeric)]
```

gets you what you want.

Answer (score 2):

`which(sapply(ds[vars], is.numeric))` should provide a vector of indices indicating columns that contain numeric data. Assuming `ds` is a data.frame or matrix object, you can then use this vector to subset your original data:

```
ids <- which(sapply(ds, is.numeric))
foo <- ds[, ids]
```

**edit:** On second thought, there's no need for `which()` at all. Just subset on the result of your `sapply()`:

```
names(ds[, sapply(ds, is.numeric)])
#[1] "MinTemp"       "MaxTemp"       "Rainfall"      "Evaporation"   "Sunshine"     
#[6] "WindGustSpeed" "WindSpeed9am"  "WindSpeed3pm"  "Humidity9am"   "Humidity3pm"  
#[11] "Pressure9am"   "Pressure3pm"   "Cloud9am"      "Cloud3pm"      "Temp9am"      
#[16] "Temp3pm"       "RISK_MM"
```

Comment: For that last suggestion, you are building a whole data.frame just to get the name of its columns. You can make better use of resources by just doing `names(ds)[sapply(ds, is.numeric)]`.

Comment: @flodel Point taken, however the call to `names()` is simply to demonstrate that the subsetting works as intended. I assumed the data itself is desirable output.