# how to summarise only numerical columns in R

Tags: r

I want to have summary of only numerical columns of R dataframe. I am doing following

```
numeric_var <- names(df)[which(sapply(df, is.numeric))]

summary(df[,.SD, .SDcols = numeric_var])
```

But, I get following error

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , .SD, .SDcols = numeric_var) : 
unused argument (.SDcols = numeric_var)
```

How can I do it in R?

Comment: `df[,c(".SD", numeric_var)]`?

Comment: In base R, you can use `summary(Filter(is.numeric, df))`.

Comment: [Find numeric columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475818/how-to-find-all-numeric-columns-in-data) and [summarise them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34405933/r-get-summary-statistics-value-in-r)

Answer (score 3):

UPDATED - June 29/2021

With the new version of `tidyverse` (`dplyr` - version `1.0.6`), we can modify the `_if` or `_all` suffix with

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    select(where(is.numeric)) 
   col2      col3
1: -0.5458808 0.6048889
2:  0.5365853 0.3707349
3:  0.4196231 0.6716903
4: -0.5836272 0.6729823
5:  0.8474600 0.3204306
```

With `summarise`, use

```
df %>% 
   summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~ list(summary(.))))
```

---

We can use `tidyverse`

```
df %>%
   select_if(is.numeric)
#         col2      col3
#1: -0.5458808 0.6048889
#2:  0.5365853 0.3707349
#3:  0.4196231 0.6716903
#4: -0.5836272 0.6729823
#5:  0.8474600 0.3204306
```

If we need to apply `summary` on the `tidyverse`

```
df %>% 
    select_if(is.numeric) %>%
    summarise_all(funs(list(summary(.))))
```

Or get the output in wide format

```
df %>%
      select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
       do(data.frame(lapply(., function(x) as.list(summary(x)))))
#    col2.Min. col2.1st.Qu. col2.Median col2.Mean col2.3rd.Qu. col2.Max. col3.Min. col3.1st.Qu. col3.Median col3.Mean col3.3rd.Qu. col3.Max.
#1 -0.5836272   -0.5458808   0.4196231 0.1348321    0.5365853   0.84746 0.3204306    0.3707349   0.6048889 0.5281454    0.6716903 0.6729823
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- which(unlist(lapply(df, is.numeric)))
```

The `summary` function can be applied separately on each column.  It is not clear about how the output should look like

```
setDT(df)[,  unlist(lapply(.SD, summary), recursive = FALSE) , .SDcols = i1]
#   col2.Min. col2.1st Qu.  col2.Median    col2.Mean col2.3rd Qu.    col2.Max.    col3.Min. col3.1st Qu.  col3.Median    col3.Mean col3.3rd Qu.    col3.Max.  
#  -0.5836272   -0.5458808    0.4196231    0.1348321    0.5365853    0.8474600    0.3204306    0.3707349    0.6048889    0.5281454    0.6716903    0.6729823
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- data.table(col1 = letters[1:5], col2 = rnorm(5), col3 = runif(5))
```

Comment: Old post, but this might be helpful to others. You can now use `summarise_if`.

Comment: @vikjam thanks, updated.  The `summarise_if` is deprecated as well

Answer (score 2):

It seems, the OP is using `data.table` syntax (i.e., `SDcols = ...`) but according to the error message `df` is only of class `data.frame`.

To use `data.table` syntax, the `data.table`package has to be loaded and `df` needs to be coerced to class `data.table`. Below is a complete example:

```
set.seed(1234L)
DF <- data.frame(a = LETTERS[1:5], b = rnorm(5), c = 1:5)
DF
#  a          b c
#1 A -1.2070657 1
#2 B  0.2774292 2
#3 C  1.0844412 3
#4 D -2.3456977 4
#5 E  0.4291247 5

numeric_var <- names(DF)[sapply(DF, is.numeric)]

library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, summary(.SD), .SDcols = numeric_var]
#       b                 c    
# Min.   :-2.3457   Min.   :1  
# 1st Qu.:-1.2071   1st Qu.:2  
# Median : 0.2774   Median :3  
# Mean   :-0.3524   Mean   :3  
# 3rd Qu.: 0.4291   3rd Qu.:4  
# Max.   : 1.0844   Max.   :5
```